# Xamarin forms: Image entry is not working as expected in android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I follow this [blog](https://xamgirl.com/image-entry-in-xamarin-forms/) for adding an image inside of an entry. It was working fine in android and IOS initially.

But when I changed the android target version and target framework to 9.0 this feature start breaking. Please see the following screenshot.

[image]

The image inside entry is zoomed in and not showing as expected. I have updated all the android SDK but no change in the output. Should I do anything else for solving this issue in android?

**My Code:**

```
 <StackLayout 
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          Padding="5"
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

          <Label
              Text="Email"
              TextColor="Black"
              FontSize="Medium"/>

           <Frame 
              CornerRadius="15"
              Padding="2,-3,-3,-3"
              HasShadow="false"
              BorderColor="#c0eefb"
              OutlineColor="#c0eefb">

               <local:ImageEntry
                    Image="ic_email_entry_image_xx"
                    x:Name="username_entry"
                    Text="charlesgeorge.admin"
                    FontSize="Medium"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Keyboard="Email"/>
           </Frame>

           <Label
               Text="Password"
                Margin="0,5,0,0"
                TextColor="Black"
                FontSize="Medium"/>

                <Frame 
                       CornerRadius="15"
                       Padding="2,-3,-3,-3"
                       HasShadow="false"
                       BorderColor="#c0eefb"
                        OutlineColor="#c0eefb">

                       <local:ImageEntry 
                              Image="ic_password_entry_image_xx"
                               x:Name="password_entry"
                                FontSize="Medium"
                                Text="admingeorge1@"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 IsPassword="True"/>
                     </Frame>

                      <Button 
                              Text="SIGN IN"
                              Margin="0,15,0,15"
                              HeightRequest="40"
                              WidthRequest="180"
                               FontSize="Large"
                               TextColor="White"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                BackgroundColor="#26B5D6" 
                                 Clicked="SignInButtonCliked"
                                  BorderRadius="20"/>
                         </Button>
</StackLayout>
```

**If I downgrade the version from 9.0(pie) to 8.1(oreo), the UI will work as expected. Why in 9.0 it is not working?**

Comment: Add relevant code please

Comment: @FreakyAli Codes added.

Comment: @FreakyAli If I downgrade the version from 9.0 to 8.1, the UI will work as expected. Why in 9.0 it is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Android 9.0(API 28) , you should provide more size of image asset .

**Solution 1:**

Put the same image in **Drawable** and **xxx-hdpi**,**xxx-mdpi** and so on .

**Solution 2:**

You can handle the different logic in different version of Android .

#### in ImageEntryRenderer

```
private BitmapDrawable GetDrawable(string imageEntryImage)
{
   int resID = Resources.GetIdentifier(imageEntryImage, "drawable", this.Context.PackageName);
   var drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this.Context, resID);
   var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;

   if(Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.P)
   {
     return new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, element.ImageWidth * 2, element.ImageHeight * 2, true));
   }

   return new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, element.ImageWidth , element.ImageHeight , true));
}
```